# Как изменить кодировку всех файлов в папке глобально?

Tags: кодировка, php

Нужно глобально изменить кодировку всех файлов проекта с `Windows-1251` на `UTF-8`. Не хочется перебирать 10000+ файлов отдельно, мне кажется есть какие-то способы для *ленивых* -)

В PHPStorm выбираю `File -> Settings -> File Encoding -> Default Encoding` - задаю `UTF-8` для всего проекта, но кодировка применяется только для новых, созданных после этого, файлов. Для уже созданных кодировка остается прежней.

И еще, в PHPStorm перекодировала файл, где присутствуют кириллические символы, так он закодировал их вопросами настолько, что в других программах все вопросами и осталось.

Есть ли программы, которые сделают это за меня, но так, чтобы без всяких BOM?

Comment: Tea Editor не справляется?

Comment: Я его поковыряла, но не нашла ничего глобального. Попробуйте, пожалуйста, рассказать, куда там копать

Comment: Хм. Что-нибудь типа

    find ./ -name '*.php' -o -name '*.html' -exec iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 {} -o {}.bak ; -exec mv {}.bak {} \;

Comment: @MyNameIs, моя вина. Как выяснилось, создатель редактора убрал массовую перекодировку на доработку. Она снова в TODO.

Comment: @alexlz, простите, а куда это писать?

Comment: Ставите cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/ ), хотя, возможно оно будет работать и в msys  ( http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS ), и в командной строке bash (можно и скриптик написать, но там некоторые доп. телодвижения

    cat >a.sh <<EOF
    #!/bin/sh
    find ./ -name '*.php' -o -name '*.html' -exec iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 {} -o {}.bak ; -exec mv {}.bak {} \;
    EOF
    chmod +x a.sh

Ну и iconv тоже следует установить (в cygwin вроде выбирается, про msys совсем не помню)

Comment: [UTFCast Express](http://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast-express.aspx) попробуйте

Comment: @yura ivanov! Вот! Вот это вы дело говорите. Как раз для бездельников. Спасибо.

Comment: Хочу добавить по поводу [UTFCast Express][1]. По началу утилитка меня порадовала, все файлы из ANSI разом перевела в UTF-8. При повторном открытии русские символы читались нормально, а позже выяснилось, что в некоторых ключевых файлах при переоткрытии русские символы стали нечитаемыми. А как работать с нечитаемыми символами...

Так что перекодировка каждого файла отдельно руками в PHP Expert Editor выиграла.)


  [1]: http://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast-express.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, сейчас скажу бред, но всё же.

Можно написать небольшую программку, примерно по следующему алгоритму: открывается файл, копируется содержимое, меняется кодировка (если не ошибаюсь, в пхп есть соответствующая функция), записывается в файл. И так прогнать по циклу все файлы.

Comment: Не бред ни разу, но программисты ленивы и склонны искать готовые решения)

Comment: Точно, это про меня

Answer (score 0):

```
function enc($file)
{
    $file = 'codes/' . $file;
    $text = file_get_contents($file);
    $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'utf-8', 'cp1251');
    unlink($file);
    $fp = fopen($file, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $text);
    fclose($fp);
}


for ($i = 1; $i <= 276; $i++) {
    enc('code'.$i.'.cpp');
}
```